# Jquery Select button(s) inside div

Tags: jquery

I would like to select a specific group of buttons that exist inside a DIV and assign their ID to a hidden field on the page but I cant for the life of me select the buttons inside the div.. Example fails below

SOURCE HTML

```
    <div id = test>
    <div class="ButtonGroupWrapper">                    
                    <img src="test.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="thumbnail" />
                <input id="buttonID5" type="submit" value="Link" class="button" />
    </div>
    <div class="ButtonGroupWrapper">                    
                    <img src="test.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="thumbnail" />
                <input id="buttonID6" type="submit" value="Link" class="button" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery selector fails

```
    $(".ButtonGroupWrapper").find(":button").click(function () {
        alert("hi there");
        return false;
    });

    $("#ButtonGroupWrapper input[type=button]").click(function () {
        alert("hi there");
        return false;
    });

    $("#ButtonGroupWrapper :button").click(function () {
        alert("hi there");
       return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".ButtonGroupWrapper").find(".button").click(function () {
        alert("hi there");
        return false;
});
```

Your first example fails because you're trying to target a class which is preceded by `.` not `:`. You may also be trying to target an element of type button but the element in question is of type submit.

Your second example fails because you're trying to select an input of type button when none exist (your target is type submit). An alternative would be `input[type=submit]`.

Your third example fails for a similar reason to the first example failing in that it's looking for an element of type button.

See also http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

Comment: Thank you very much. I went with the first one changing the :button to :submit   $(".ButtonGroupWrapper").find(":submit").click(function () {
        alert("hi there");
        return false;
    });

Answer (score 11):

Putting a space looks for any .button class within your .ButtonGroupWrapper class. (NOTE: not any 'button', but anything with the code class="button" added to it)

```
$(".ButtonGroupWrapper .button").click(function () {
    alert("hello");
    return false;
});
```

In your HTML code the submit input has a 'class' of 'button'. 
It could actually be anything such as  .strawberry or .mybutton or anything you like.

**Alternative:**

As you have an id wrapping the whole lot you could also target button within the id:

```
<div id ="test">
  <div>                    
    <img src="test.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="thumbnail" />
    <input type="submit" value="Link" class="button" />
  </div>
  <div>                     
    <img src="test.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="thumbnail" />
    <div class="button" />Just text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then your javascript could be:

```
$("#test .button").click(function () {
     alert("button class clicked");
    return false;
});
```

Remember you need to run this after the DOM has loaded, so best practice is to either write it at the end of the page or wrap it in your favourite onready function.

Comment: While it is great you are contributing to the site, please note the **date** and **status** of the original question. The question was posted **1 year ago** and the author has already accepted a very good, complete answer (note the green checkmark next to j08691's answer). Typically, unless there are no answers at all (or only very poor and incomplete answers), you should avoid answering questions older than a few months. The same goes for answering questions that already have an accepted answer. *accepted* means the OP has effectively said his question is answered.

Comment: @Daniel, actually, I think Digital added some very useful information not present in the accepted answer.  I, for one, am glad the new answer was posted!

Comment: I would second that notion Daniel, I also found that additional information helpful. Digital Visual added information to the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(".ButtonGroupWrapper").find(".button").click(function () {
    alert("hi there");
    return false;
});
```